# MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit confused on how to order by date formats.

For the format `YYYY-MM-DD` you would do this: `...ORDER BY date DESC...`

How would you order by `DD/MM/YYYY`?

This isn't working:

```
SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y%m%d') DESC LIMIT 14
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your strings to MySQL date values and `ORDER BY` the result:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

However, you would be wise to convert the column to the `DATE` data type instead of using strings.

Answer (score 252):

Guessing you probably just want to format the output date? then this is what you are after

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS niceDate 
FROM table 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0,14
```

Or do you actually want to sort by Day before Month before Year?

Comment: I would like the 14 latest date/records :)
The format in the database is "DD/MM/YYYY" though!

Comment: Is the date in the database an actual date type, or is it a string type?

Comment: `mysql> DESCRIBE Table;` and paste the output

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date,'%a') will give a day of week abbreviation. I used this for making some boxplots and such in RStudio.

Answer (score 47):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(somedate, "%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date
..........
ORDER BY formatted_date DESC
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does the `%l` not work? It gives `12` for every month and I had to change to `%m`.

Comment: %l is for hours https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format @beroe

Answer (score 43):

Use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NAME_COLUMN, "%d/%l/%Y") AS 'NAME'
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NAME_COLUMN, "%d/%l/%Y %H:%i:%s") AS 'NAME'
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 27):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(COLUMN_NAME, "%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p");
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2019-05-10 19:30:10", "%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p");
```

> OUTPUT is **10/05/2019 07:30 PM**

Answer (score 6):

for my case this worked

```
str_to_date(date, '%e/%m/%Y' )
```

Answer (score 6):

If the hour is important, I used `str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y %T' )`, the `%T` shows the hour in the format `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: It's not referred to as hour. `%T` shows the value with time format. By the way, you got my upvote.

Answer (score 6):

**This image will help you.**

[image: Date Format]

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2019-05-10 19:30:10", "%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p");
```

Comment: thanks. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 5):

ORDER BY a date type does not depend on the date format, the date format is only for showing, in the database, they are same data.

Comment: Format can be used to sort (if someone really want, seems strange for me), but such sort cannot be based on index, so [b]is costly[/b], Only sort over good designed columns can be executed with index (fast) and optimised by server