# MySql order by (varchar) date in Mmm-dd-yyyy

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

So unfortunately I have a VARCHAR column of dates formatted like so:  Jun-13-2013

(I understand that this is done incorrectly and should be stored in a DATETIME column in the standard format)

I'm trying to grab all the data in every row and ORDER by that VARCHAR column as a DATETIME, but I'm not finding anything out there to convert my poorly formatted date column for sorting.

here is my query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM archive ORDER BY crapdates DESC");
```

But I'm trying to convert the `crapdates` column to a datetime... is this even possible?

[I'm not finding a mmm-dd-yyyy format conversion anywhere](http://asmaqureshi.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-convert-from-string-to-date.html)

Thanks for checking it out

Comment: is the data in `crapdates` consistently formatted, or stored in multiple ways (i.e., Jun-13-2013, 06-13-13, etc.)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert your existing varchar column to a date value.

I'd definitely recommend creating a new column and using `STR_TO_DATE()` to copy the value from your existing column into the new column, rather than using `STR_TO_DATE()` directly in the `ORDER BY` of your `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE archive SET newdate = STR_TO_DATE(crapdate,'%b-%e-%Y');
```

If you can't change the table structure, you can sort on the existing column like this:

```
SELECT * FROM archive ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(crapdate,'%b-%e-%Y') DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

"You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your strings to MySQL date values and `ORDER BY` the result:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

However, you would be wise to convert the column to the `DATE` data type instead of using strings."

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637668/1146492 by xdazz

Answer (score 0):

I tried str_to_date but it was not returning desire result then i found this code, but in my case date was in this format 03/15/2021

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(crapdates, 7) DESC, ORDER BY SUBSTR(crapdates, 1,2) DESC,ORDER BY SUBSTR(crapdates, 4,2) DESC
```

It will return your desire sorting.