# MySQL DATE_FORMAT()

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to format date using MySQL DATE_FORMAT. My Query is

```
SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, DATE_FORMAT(added_date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS AddDate
FROM profiles.
```

added_date is the date field on profile table, when I run that query it brings Null for AddDate, any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Is added_date stored as a date or as an INT?

Comment: what's the type of added_date column and what is displayed if you get this not formatted? I assume this column is not null for all profiles? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments you are probably looking for this

```sql
SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, 
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p'),'%d/%m/%Y') AS AddDate
FROM profiles
```

Sample output:

```
| FIRST_NAME | MIDDLE_NAME | LAST_NAME |    ADDDATE |
-----------------------------------------------------
|       Jhon |      (null) |       Doe | 11/08/2013 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9208/2)** demo

Comment: Still the same, it's so weird

Comment: What is the data type of `added_date`? Please post `DESC profiles`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're storing it as an INT you might need to use FROM_UNIXTIME()

```
SELECT 
  first_name, 
  middle_name, 
  last_name, 
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(added_date),'%d/%m/%Y') AS AddDate
FROM 
  profiles
```

Comment: But in your question you mentioned that added_date is the Date field and FROM_UNIXTIME() is for Int. :(

Comment: My datatype is Varchar() When I run your code it display 01/01/1970 I realize datatype is the issue of this problem, either I will have to modify table.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like t his using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):-

```
SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s A'),'%d/%m/%Y') AS AddDate
FROM profiles
```

Answer (score 0):

find edited query

```
    SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, 
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(added_date, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s A'),'%d/%m/%Y') AS AddDate
    FROM profiles
```

[Reference question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Comment: Still doesn't work, let me tell you what I want to accomplish. That added_date is in this format right now 11-08-2013 09:02:25 AM, I just want to display 11/08/2013. How I can format to that.