# how to change date format of mysql table column

Tags: mysql

I have created a table called event and it has a column birthday which is using the date format of 
`%Y-%m-%d` but I want it to be `%d-%m-%Y`. so, how can i update it?

when I enter new row with the format `%d-%m-%Y`  it converts it to `0000-00-00 (%Y-%m-%d)`

I tried following Queries to change format but it isn't working.

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename`

After executing this query it says rows affected and making all the values 0**000-00-00**.

Comment: The first query should work. As far as the second is concern what data type is for `column_name` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty im using date format to that column

Comment: Yes the query shows that, but where is the issue ? Are you facing this issue while saving the data ? if yes then you need to use str_to_date() from the input format to the mysql format Y-m-d, and make sure that the column where you are saving is of datatype `date` or `datetime`. The conversion while saving could be done using the application level language like for example PHP

Comment: Are you trying to store, in the database date column, a string of format 'DD/MM/YYYY'? if so then please do not do that. Store the date as format 'YYYY-MM-DD', change the format to whatever you want when displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I tried and works for me.

select DATE_FORMAT(birthday , '%d/%m/%Y') from event;

But what data type you have for birthday?

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query) example.

Comment: So the code I posted should work. I updated my answer with an example question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateColumn FROM table
```

Comment: What does dateColumn means?

Comment: @ShaBeer your column name.

Comment: Your query affecting all the existing column but when i try to insert new one It says Data truncated for column 'birthday' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert (or update) a date which isn't in the right format u can use

```
INSERT INTO `event` (columname) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('30/09/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```