# Rails is not handling my dates properly when saving to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date, date-format

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and MySql 5.5.37.  In my table, I have a column of type DATE,  In my application, dates are chosen with the Jquery date picker and maintain the format, “mm/dd/yy” (this cannot change right now).  However, in my Rails controller, when I go to save the model from the submitted form, with the date “02/10/2016” (February 10th, 2016)

```
@user_object = UserObject.new(user_object_params)
```

the date gets saved as “2016-10-02”.  Is there anything I can do on the server side to save the dates the right way?  Converting them on the client side right before submission seems a little messy.

Comment: Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query). I think it may answer yours.

Comment: I"m not understanding how this question is relevant.  How do I convert the format from whcih the string is submitted into something MySql will udnerstand in my Rails code/config?