# How to have a sort of sub-aggregate in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am racking my brain trying find a solution to this - if it is possible. I need to count the number of actions per user per period per code where multiple actions on the same day on the same reference return 1. Simplified example:

```
Table log:
Date, user, reference, code

1/1/2016 09:21, user-A, ref-123, 1
2/1/2016 10:30, user-A, ref-745, 1
2/1/2016 09:20, user-B, ref-234, 1
2/1/2016 09:25, user-B, ref-234, 1
2/1/2016 10:25, user-B, ref-234, 1
3/1/2016 10:00, user-C, ref-543, 1
3/1/2016 10:30, user-D, ref-123, 1
4/2/2016 12:45, user-A, ref-778, 3
etc.
```

If I run this query

```
SELECT user, count(*) 
FROM log
WHERE date between '20160101' AND '20160131' AND code = 1
GROUP BY user
```

I get

```
User-A  2
User-B  3
```

But what I really need is user-B to have a count of 1 as all actions occurring on the same day on the same reference should count as one. I am stumped.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use `group by` on a truncated version of  your Date, that does not contain the time.  
Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query to do the truncation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT user, count(distinct date(date)) 
FROM log
WHERE date between '20160101' AND '20160131' AND code = 1
GROUP BY user;
```