# date format in sql query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format

I am trying to change the format in the result view for column name GroupingDate.
The current result is `2016-01-01 00:00:00`.

I want to see result like this,
`1/1/2016`

current query is

```
select GroupingDate, SEQ, SentAsReprint
from tproduction
where jobnumber = '111000_01'
```

Comment: i do not want to see leading 0 in month or date.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using.

Comment: Is that `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Comment: Use `convert()`:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That would be the answer, but op said in a comment that there shouldn't be a leading `0` in month or day

Comment: You need to use `FORMAT`: `SELECT FORMAT(YourDate, 'M/d/YYYY')` or `SELECT FORMAT(YourDate, 'd/M/YYYY')`

Comment: Formatting belongs in the consuming application. You should have your queries return the datetime datatype.

Comment: @Lamak. when you say YourDate, do you mean my column name?

Comment: @BinitPatel yes, of course

Comment: thank you @Lamak it is working. awesome thanks. Only thing I had to change was yyyy from YYYY. Format(GroupingDate, 'M/d/yyyy') as [GroupingDate]

Answer (score 2):

The SQL function FORMAT can help you doing this.

```
 SELECT FORMAT(column_name,"M/D/YYYY") FROM table_name;
```

If you are using MySQL, there also is

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,format)
```

Sources :
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_format.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp
[MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Comment: As you thanked @Lamak for the same answer, could you flag as accepted answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this kind of formatting should be applied outside of the query as the client/application may have other display preferences, however, it is totally doable in sql. [Here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) is a link.

Answer (score 0):

Format(GroupingDate, 'M/d/yyyy') as [GroupingDate]
this is working perfectly fine.
thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result with converting to string format.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GroupingDate, 101), SEQ, SentAsReprint
from tproduction
where jobnumber = '111000_01'
```

OR

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GroupingDate, 103), SEQ, SentAsReprint
from tproduction
where jobnumber = '111000_01'
```