# Mysql syntax error in (DATE_SUB(REPLACE(CURDATE(), '-', ''), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1);

Tags: mysql

My date format is: `YYYYMMDD`

```
CURDATE() returns: YYYY-MM-DD
```

I want weekly records for started_on and failed using mysql so tried:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1), failed FROM 1_results WHERE (DATE_SUB(REPLACE(CURDATE(), '-', ''), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1);
```

But getting error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2
```

Tried `DATEDIFF` as well but no luck.

Individually running `SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1) and REPLACE(CURDATE(), '-', '')` works fine but above query fails.

Comment: What is the type of `started_on` in your table ?

Comment: varchar (not date) :)

Comment: Ok then you should really  consider switching to a date format, because date comparisons are way easier that way.

Comment: I can't. I just want weekly records in search result. I tried converting format using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query as well but no luck.

Comment: Sample table & data: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1_results` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `machine` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `started_on` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `1_results` (`id`, `sender`, `machine`, `started_on`, `duration`, `status`) VALUES
(1, '10.15.4.9', 'm1', '20150514 - 235440', '12 min', 'Completed'),
(2, '10.15.4.9', 'm2', '20150515 - 003651', '15 min', 'Completed'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `started_on` is a string, the best thing to do will be to convert this as a proper MySQL date using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, like this :

```
STR_TO_DATE(started_on, '%Y%m%d')
```

That will be return a proper date that you then can use to easily make comparisons. The only thing that is still to change is the part where you subtract 7 days from the current date. You really over-complicated it, you just need :

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

So your whole query just becomes :

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1), failed FROM 1_results 
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= STR_TO_DATE(started_on, '%Y%m%d') ;
```

Comment: Thanks Loufylouf. Your query partially worked, it just returns 1 record in the result instead of many. SELECT SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1), failed FROM 1_results WHERE (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= STR_TO_DATE(started_on, '%Y%m%d')) and (suite = 'Full') and (status = 'Completed') and (started_on is not null) and (failed is not null) and (started_on <> '-') and (failed <> '-') and (started_on <> '') and (failed <> ''); It would be great if you resolve this issue for me.

Comment: In short it gives record of 1 week only (last week).

Comment: Ok, i have made it working using your query but new problem, it doesn't look into previous year and just returns 2016 records weekly. $sql="SELECT SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1) as started_on, failed FROM 1_results WHERE (DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= DATE_FORMAT(SPLIT_STR(started_on, ' - ', 1), '%Y%m%d')) and (status = 'Completed') and (started_on is not null) and (failed is not null) and (started_on <> '-') and (failed <> '-') and (started_on <> '') and (failed <> '')"; Any clue? Help needed.