# How to Insert a Date into Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How can I Insert a Date into the database, in a format that when inserted, will appear "April 30th, 3:45am" rather than the default which is "2015, 4, 30 03:46"

I am thinking if there is a way I could do this with a javascript code?

Comment: don't there are real good reasons to use the databases format. you just change it on display. Also Javascript is client side, your database is server side. Aos mysql format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: There are multiple ways to do basic string or locale operations at any level to change how your date is displayed.  For assistance in correcting how you display it right now, show us the code that displays it and the input it receives.

Comment: See the second answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query

Comment: i think best you use database format that is date("Y-m-d"), because when you need sort by date in your project that only easy to sort. So when you display it , change the date format, that is date("F d, Y H:i a",strtotime($date))

Answer (score 0):

Just don't insert a Date as a string in your database, store it as a DateTime. It's a really bad practice to store dates as strings in databases because you cannot change it's format at all, or order them in a query later.

You can pass it from the database through PHP into the page in the format the database outputs it.

Then convert it to desired format with JavaScript using the library [moment](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var dateAsString = moment(dateFromDatabase, 'YYYY, M, d, hh:mm').format('MMMM Do, h:mma');
```

In fact this:

```
moment('2015, 4, 30 03:46', 'YYYY, M, d, hh:mm').format('MMMM Do, h:mma');
```

Outputs:

> April 1st, 3:46am