# How to format date column in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, format

I have a date column with the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but I want to format all the values in the column to `DD-MM-YYYY` in mysql

Comment: A date column has no format.

Comment: Have a look at the manual and you will have your answer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: `SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: You format this when you present it in some way. Dont try and change the way MYSQL holds this information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Comment: but when i am subtracting all the values in that column by 7 days by using DATE_SUB() function then i am not getting anything

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_format`:

```
date_format(yourcolumn, '%d-%m-%Y')
```