# How to fetch date(d,m,y) from phpmyadmin in php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to fetch date format from (y,m,d) to (d,m,y).In my database I already insert data like date and images so many around 400 images.I dun want to insert again.[image: phpmyadmin]

The following  is to fetch from database.

```
<?              
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM  ShowFillter GROUP BY Image_Date order by Image_Date desc";
                            $objQuery = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
                            while($objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="<?=$objResult1['Image_Date'];?>">
                            <a href="#">
                                <?=$objResult1['Image_Date'];?></a>
                        </li>

                        <? 
                            }    
                        ?>
```

The following is i tried it out to fetch from database.But It only show (Year ,Month,day) format.

```
<?              
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM  ShowFillter GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Image_Date, '%d/%m/%Y') order by DATE_FORMAT(Image_Date, '%d/%m/%Y') desc";
                            $objQuery = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
                            while($objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="<?=$objResult1['Image_Date'];?>">
                            <a href="#">
                                <?=$objResult1['Image_Date'];?></a>
                        </li>

                        <? 
                            }    
                        ?>
```

Here is the result 
[image: result]
Is it possible to fetch (day,month,year) format?
If its possible ,guide me please.

Thanks :)

Comment: code image will not help to check the problem. put your code here in text.

Comment: First of all, I'd suggest you not to use `mysql_* ` functions as they are deprecated. Another thing, do you want to format the date in query or php code?

Comment: Do you want to display the Date in d-m-y ?

Comment: yes i want to display the date in d-m-y @HardikPatel

Comment: @AJ       I edited my question sir check it .

Comment: @Dave i edited sir ,help me out

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query also 1000 other dupes.

Comment: try this in side while loop , <?php
$temp_date = $objResult1['Image_date'];
$date=date_create($temp_date);
$Image_Date =  date_format($date,"d m Y");

?>
<li class="filter" data-filter="<?=$Image_Date;?>">
    <a href="#"><?=$Image_Date;?></a>
</li>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you print your image date do:

```
<?=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($objResult1['Image_Date])); ?>
```

This will echo 27-12-2013

More here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: [link](https://postimg.org/image/fpplmsutv/) but its not still correct to me ,i believe its near to get correct  Thanks

Comment: I corrected a typo in the array key. It was geting 1/1/1970 because it was null. Try again

Comment: u saved my life,i got that thanks :)

Comment: do people just randomly downvote!?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this in your query, so the date is already formatted.

```
SELECT id, Image_Id, Image_Name, Image_Type, DATE_FORMAT(Image_Date, '%d,%m,%y') AS Image_Date, `status` 
FROM ShowFilter 
GROUP BY Image_Date 
ORDER BY Image_Date DESC
```

Read [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the output in php using `strtotime` and `date`:

```
$new_Image_Date = date("d,m,Y", strtotime($objRsult1['Image_Date']));
```

`strtotime` takes the string that's returned from your query and parses it into a timestamp. You can then convert it to the correct format using `date`.

So your snippet would ultimately be something like:

```
<?              
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM  ShowFillter GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Image_Date, '%d/%m/%Y') order by DATE_FORMAT(Image_Date, '%d/%m/%Y') desc";
  $objQuery = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
  while($objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
  {
?>
<li class="filter" data-filter="<?=date("d,m,Y", strtotime($objResult1['Image_Date']));?>">
   <a href="#">
     <?=date("d,m,Y", strtotime($objResult1['Image_Date']));?>
   </a>
</li>
<? 
  }    
?>
```

Check the references below if you need more info:

[strtotime() doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[date() doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: It show me like that photo [link](https://postimg.org/image/fpplmsutv/) but i think its near to get solution.

Comment: Well that's how your code was :) I guess you would just use `$objResult1['Image_Name']` inside a `div` or `img` tag to display the picture. For example `<img src="<?=$objResult1['Image_Name']?>">`

Comment: you save my life ,i got that thanks :)