# PHP - mysql sort order by month and year from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, sql-order-by

I everyone I am afzal and I have stored data in my database with custom date (mm-yy) that looks like this **01-2018** *(month-year)* .

> and now I want to fetch my data by custom date in desc or asc order
>   Please tell me how can I fetch my data from mysql in desc or asc order by custom date like this **01-2018**  ...Thanks

Comment: Always store dates in DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP fields. Then this would be easy

Comment: You can customise the date you show to your users then anyway you like. But always start from a basic column data type from above set

Comment: What data type is your custom date held in please?

Comment: my Data type is varchar  and I don't want to set it as date or timestamp I have to store only month and year . and I have to retrieve my data by this custom date order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)