# How to Sort Varchar date in Descending order MySql?

Tags: mysql

I'm storing datetime in varchar in my table. This my datetime format : `12/13/2019 12:05:30 PM`.
I want to sort these date in descending order. 
This is my sql

```
SELECT CreatedOn FROM advweb_usertemplatedesign Where UserId = 'fa69147ca33746cd8700a892298b11de' And ActiveStatus = 1 Order by CreatedOn Desc Limit 20
```

The result I'm getting is

```
12/5/2019 5:48:19 PM
12/4/2019 4:49:10 PM
12/3/2019 5:57:16 PM
12/13/2019 12:05:30 PM
12/12/2019 6:01:31 PM
```

Instead of

```
12/13/2019 12:05:30 PM
12/12/2019 6:01:31 PM
12/5/2019 5:48:19 PM
12/4/2019 4:49:10 PM
12/3/2019 5:57:16 PM
```

How to properly sort it? Thank you.

Comment: you should store date in `datetime` type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Comment: @DevsiOdedra no, it doesn't. Now getting 11/26/2019 3:21:36 PM, 11/27/2019 4:56:11 PM, 12/13/2019 12:05:30 PM, 11/27/2019 5:35:32 PM....it kinda mixed up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid storing your dates as strings.  As a temporary workaround, you may use MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function here:

```
SELECT CreatedOn
FROM advweb_usertemplatedesign
WHERE
    UserId = 'fa69147ca33746cd8700a892298b11de' AD
    ActiveStatus = 1
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(CreatedOn, '%m/%d/%Y %r') DESC
LIMIT 20;
```