# PHP query for date filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

How I can filter a table's data when the field's type is stored as `varchar` and its format is `dd/mm/yyyy`?

I'm attaching a screenshot.

[image]

It only filters based on day, it will not check the month and year.
If an SQL solution is not available then please tell me how I can handle this in PHP.

Comment: Convert stored data (and criteria if needed) into DATE datatype then filter. But the best way is to alter the column and set DATE datatype for it.

Comment: The proper solution would be to convert that column into an actual date column and transform the data, then you can filter directly. Otherwise, see [this relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query).

Comment: .. or at least alter storing format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd - this allows to compare dates correctly in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to update the column to date by `STR_TO_DATE` in order to not lost data when alter it, then alter the column and set DATE as datatype for it.

```sql
UPDATE `details` SET `datenew` = STR_TO_DATE(`datenew`, "%d/%m/%Y");
ALTER TABLE `details` MODIFY `datenew` DATE
```

Then you can easily run your query

```sql
SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE `datenew` >= str_to_date('23/06/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: it is work but  there is not any separate query for filter this data base on that format

Answer (score 0):

You can str_to_date the varchar datatype to date in the WHERE clause

```sql
SELECT * FROM details WHERE str_to_date(datenew, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '20200603'
```

Comment: not working this

Comment: Apologies I wrote this in MSSQL, I've updated it to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column to a date!  You can do this in a `where` clause:

```
where str_to_date(datecol, '%d/%m/%Y') >= ? and
      str_to_date(datecol, '%d/%m/%Y') < ?
```

However, the correct thing to do is to store the data using the correct type:

```
update t
    set datecol = date_format(str_to_date(datecol, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');

alter table t modify column datecol date;
```