# How to format the date with month/day/year from Sun May 04 1980 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) in nodejs javascript mysql

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

This is the code of the main page like in the screenshot. Using mysql to get that data, it is a CRUD application with nodejs, express, mysql and bootstrap. Don't know how to format the date to (month/day/year) instead of (Sun May 04 1980 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)). Please help. New to javascript programming, so i am struggling :(
[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><h1>Users</h1></div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <a href="/adduser" type="button" class="btn btn-primary align-self-center">+ add new user</a>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
      <th scope="col">DoB</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-end">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    {{#each rows}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{this.id}}</th>
      <td>{{this.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.dob}}</td>
      <td>{{this.phone}}</td>
      <td class="text-end">
          <a href="/viewuser/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i> View</a>
          <a href="/edituser/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</a>
          <a href="/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-person-x"></i> Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}

  </tbody>
</table>

// View users
exports.view = (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) =>{
    if(err) throw err; // not connected
    console.log('DB connected as ID' + connection.threadId);
    // User the connection
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users ', (err, rows)=> {
    // When done with the connection, release it
    connection.release();
        if(!err){
            let removedUser = req.query.removed;
            res.render('home', { rows, removedUser });
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: You can use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ library for hangling dates

Comment: What format (or Object) are you saving the date in express?

Comment: @KaranGaur it is mysql date format that is being displayed at the moment

Comment: Simply update the SQL Query in your express to fetch date in required format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query

Comment: @JatinMehrotra how do i use momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying? i wrote that i am new to js, i dont know how u use these libraries and where to post. Please guide properly

Comment: @KaranGaur do u mean here?
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users ', (err, rows)=> {

Comment: Add your express endpoint as well to your question

Comment: What do you mean by express endpoint?

Comment: Could you share the code where you are fetching the values from the database within your express ..

Comment: @KaranGaur please see the post, I have updated it in the code above

Comment: Update the following line "connection.query('SELECT * FROM users ', (err, rows)=> {" in your code to "connection.query('SELECT all_columns_except_DOB, DATE_FORMAT( DOB, "%m/%d/%y") as DOB FROM users ', (err, rows)=> {"

Comment: sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'all_columns_except_DOB' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'SELECT all_columns_except_DOB, DATE_FORMAT( DOB, "%m/%d/%y") as DOB FROM users '
give this error :(

Comment: Since i dont know about the colmns in your DB, add all columns there that are required manually... Hence - "all_columns_except_DOB". So if you have columns like Fname Sname, replace the string "all_columns_except_DOB" with "Fname, Sname, etc..."

Comment: My columns are id, first_name, last_name, dob, phone, comments

Comment: then replace with this 
"SELECT id, first_name, last_name, phone, comments, DATE_FORMAT( dob, "%m/%d/%y") as dob FROM users"

Comment: sqlMessage: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( dob, "%m/%d/%y") as dob FROM users' at line 1`,
Gives this error

Comment: My bad, forgot to put a comma after comment, thank you very much @KaranGaur!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the Date format in your SQL query while fetching values. Simply mention the required date format and pass the value to your view engine.

```
connection.query('SELECT all_required_columns, DATE_FORMAT(dob, "%m/%d/%y") as dob FROM users ', (err, rows)=> {
```

This should fetch all values from the DB with DOB format as mm/dd/yy.
PS: The North Remembers

Comment: Thank you, but it only works when:
connection.query('SELECT id, first_name, last_name, dob, phone, comments, DATE_FORMAT( dob, "%m/%d/%") as dob FROM users ', (err, rows)=>

Comment: Bro.... "all_required_columns" means add the columns as per your need. This is not a SQL Keyword. Anyways if this helped please approve the answer.

Comment: Well noted. Thank you again, and could not give a vote to your answer, dont have enough points :( although I pressed the tick button, hope it worked.