# Get Todays Date in MM/DD/YYYY format in MySQl

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format

I want to get Today's date in MySQL in this specific MM/DD/YYYY format. I have tried a couple of options but still, I am not getting results.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "%m/%d/%Y")

Answer (score 0):

CURDATE() will return current date

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'MM-dd-yyyy') as date