# Sort on string as date on MySql

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

I have CHAR strings stored in the database field in the format mm/dd/yyyy. Such as

```
2/26/2022
2/19/2022
2/12/2022
2/5/2022
12/31/2021
12/18/2021
11/27/2021
```

I need to sort them as shown according to the "date" without changing the declaration.

The post at [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query) suggested using ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')

My MySQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT stringdate
FROM mytable
WHERE product = '#myproduct#'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(stringdate, '%m/%d/%y') DESC
```

However, the result is not sorted properly.  Instead of the desired order as shown above, it is showing like this:

```
12/31/2021
12/18/2021
11/27/2021
2/26/2022
2/19/2022
2/12/2022
2/5/2022
```

It seems that the year is being ignored.  How can I sort this without actually changing the database field declaration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gotta wonder why you didn't check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the right format strings. `%y` expects a two-digit year, `%d` expects a two-digit day, `%m` expects a two digiti month. You could fix your format string, but make life easy for yourself and switch these dates to a ` DATE` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2/5/2022` is month and day without leading zeros, and four digit year. The format string you have specified is -

- %m - Month, numeric (00..12)
- %d - Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
- %y - Year, numeric (two digits)

```sql
SELECT stringdate
FROM mytable
WHERE product = '#myproduct#'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(stringdate, '%c/%e/%Y') DESC
```

- %c - Month, numeric (0..12)
- %e - Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
- %Y - Year, numeric, four digits

Executing the following query shows the difference in the converted dates -

```sql
SELECT
    stringdate, 
    STR_TO_DATE(stringdate, '%m/%d/%y'), 
    STR_TO_DATE(stringdate, '%c/%e/%Y')
FROM mytable
WHERE product = '#myproduct#'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(stringdate, '%c/%e/%Y') DESC
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2dfef24a4eacc7da87ad280ba482c84a)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

`%y` is the two-digit year code. So you are sorting them all as '20'

`%Y` is the four-digit year code.

See reference for the date format codes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

I recommend you use the `DATE` data type instead of `CHAR`.

Comment: Plus one for explaining "why". Also agreed that using a proper date column is preferred to storing strings...